# How do I get certain links from a website, but not all of them?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def linkScraper():
    html = requests.get("https://www.bbc.com/").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

But this prints every single link on the website. How can I configure this to give me the links to the articles that appear on the BBC's homepage?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it with list comprehension:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def linkScraper():
    html = requests.get("https://www.bbc.com/").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    links = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a') if link['href'].startswith('https://www.bbc.com/')]

    for i in links:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Where would I insert this line into my code? I put it before the for loop but it had the error of "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"